# Don't want double quotes around json file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to construct a json file from python where the commas after each object and front and back brackets don't have quotes around it.

I'm currently getting

```
"["{"indicator": "ohzhsjsj", "start_date": 20031202, "reported_by":
"jvayusnx", "number": 92, "is_submitted": true}","{"indicator":
"zgsedxpy", "start_date": 19782004, "reported_by": "lxyhnvhy",
"number": 58, "is_submitted": true}"]"
```

where I want

```
[{"indicator": "ohzhsjsj", "start_date": 20031202, "reported_by":
"jvayusnx", "number": 92, "is_submitted": true} , {"indicator":
"zgsedxpy", "start_date": 19782004, "reported_by": "lxyhnvhy",
"number": 58, "is_submitted": true}]
```

my code below

```
     if currentcount == 0:
         varr = '['
         json.dump(varr, json_file)
     json.dump(dict, json_file)
     if currentcount < runcount:
         varr = ',';
         json.dump(varr, json_file)
     if currentcount == runcount:
         varr = ']'
         json.dump(varr, json_file) 
     currentcount += 1
```

Comment: Why don't you just put all your `dicts` into a `list` and `json.dump` that?

Comment: Construct an actual `list` and then `json.dump()` the list. You are dumping a string, which gets quoted.

Comment: Thanks both of you. That ended up working.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.